# Regex get data after |

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

This is my log

```
2022-06-29 12:45:04.652 | INFO     | product.views.product_view:list:28 - SEARCH | Humana papa 
2022-06-29 12:45:04.652 | INFO     | product.views.product_view:list:28 - SEARCH | iPhone 12
```

i want to get everything after `Search |` for example
**Humana papa |
iphone 12**

i am using regex  , i try this code but its only get Humana and iphone
r'SEARCH | (\w+).*'

```
import re
from collections import Counter

inp = """2022-06-29 12:45:04.652 | INFO     | product.views.product_view:list:28 - SEARCH | Humana
2022-06-29 12:45:04.652 | INFO     | product.views.product_view:list:28 - SEARCH | Car
2022-06-29 12:45:04.652 | INFO     | product.views.product_view:list:28 - SEARCH | Phone 12 pro
2022-06-29 12:45:04.652 | INFO     | product.views.product_view:list:28 - SEARCH | Humana papa """
terms = re.findall(r'SEARCH \| (\w+).*', inp)

print(Counter(terms))  # Counter({'Humana': 2, 'Car': 1, 'Phone': 1})
print(Counter(terms).most_common(1)[0])  # ('Humana', 2)
```

what is best way to get full word ?

Comment: Just use `r'SEARCH\s*\|\s*(\S.*)'`

Comment: Can you explain what  this mean ? \s*(\S.*

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: To avoid escaping special characters you can use the `(backtick) instead of " when quoting strings. For example `\w+` is the same as "\\w+".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
terms = re.findall(r'SEARCH\s*\|\s*(\S.*)', inp.strip())
```

Note the `inp.strip()` where the `inp` string is stripped from the intial/trailing whitespace.

The regex matches

- `SEARCH` - a `SEARCH` word
- `\s*\|\s*` - a `|` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S.*)` - Group 1: a non-whitespace and then the rest of the line.

Output:

```
>>> terms
['Humana', 'Car', 'Phone 12 pro', 'Humana papa']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKp17K/1).

Comment: why is this error when i try
((  this code --- > r'SEARCH\s*\|\s*(\S.*)'    ))
 in Loki grafana using regexp but there is error

Make sure that all special characters are escaped with \

Comment: @pataradzmaa The answer is for Python. I do not know how you use it in Loki grafana. Check [this documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/).

Comment: To avoid escaping special characters you can use the `(backtick) instead of " when quoting strings. For example `\w+` is the same as "\\w+".